# Sails.js can't run script: sails run rebuild-cloud-sdk

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm having an issue running: `sails run rebuild-cloud-sdk`

I get the following error: `Could not regenerate the configuration for the "Cloud SDK" -- the JavaScript module used for AJAX and WebSockets. TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined`

this is the line that causes the error in the script file:

```
await sails.helpers.fs.write.with({
```

Any ideas what could be wrong tried to google for solutions but couldn't find anything. I have a suspicion that it may todo with config as I started out with an empty sails app.

EDIT:

the function that fails is being called from the script file, which you can find in Sails.js seed app (LINE 115): https://github.com/balderdashy/seed/blob/master/scripts/rebuild-cloud-sdk.js

Comment: Where is this code placed? What file?

Comment: @Noitidart just edited the question

Comment: Start modifying the code around line 115 to `console.log` stuff to investigate. That will help you fix it for sure.

Comment: @Noitidart looks I have tried to console.log sails.helpers to see if it will return .fs method, but it doesn't. Not sure what is the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I figured that I'm unable to use any kind of helpers, further googling lead me to https://github.com/sailshq/sails-hook-organics. Turns outs I needed to run following command:

```
npm install sails-hook-organics --save
```

When building my application have chosen an empty seed (your to configure) and that is what caused my problem.

Comment: Interesting Sam thanks for sharing! So you didn't chose "Web App" on `sails init`?

Comment: @Noitidart since my app didn't need authentication or user registration I chose `Empty`, I figured that I won't have to delete redundant code this way. Obviously didn't realize that I will need to install the helpers that kinda look like they should be in by default. And it's not much information about it.